# Bounded linear operator in weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, continuity

Let $B$ be a bounded linear operator on $H$. Prove $B\colon (H,w)\to (H,w)$ is continuous. $(H,w)$ is a Hilbert space with its weak topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ is linear, we need only show that $B$ is weakly continuous at zero.

Suppose $V$ is a weak neighborhood of $0$. Then $V$ contains a set of the form $W = \{ x \,|\,  |\phi_k(x)| < \epsilon, \ k \in I\}$, where $I$ is a finite set of indices and $\phi_k \in \mathbb{H}^*$. Then we need to find a weak neighborhood $U$ of $0$ such that $BU \subset W$.

Explicitly, we need to find $U$ such that if $x \in U$, then $|\phi_k(B(x))| < \epsilon$ for all $k \in I$. This suggests the form of $U$, using the adjoint of $B$ seems particularly promising, noting that $\phi_k(B(x)) = (B^* \phi_k)(x)$.

So, we let $U = \{ x \,|\,  |(B^* \phi_k)(x)| < \epsilon, \ k \in I\}$. Then if $x \in U$ we have $|\phi_k(B(x))| < \epsilon$ for all $k \in I$, and hence $B(x) \in W \subset V$.